# OCaml - Parsing command-line options with arguments using Arg

Tags: ocaml, command-line-arguments

I want to parse command line options with arguments in OCaml.

The module `Arg` of the standard library seems to do everything I need and there are some tutorials which explain how to use this module.

My problem is, that they all seem to share the same strange behavior when the argument of an option is missing. For example, executing the program from [this example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Command-line_arguments#OCaml) with `./a.out -d` produces the following output:

```
./a.out: option '-d' needs an argument.
usage: ./a.out [-b] [-s string] [-d int]
  -b : set somebool to true
  -s : what follows -s sets some string
  -d : some int parameter
  -help  Display this list of options
  --help  Display this list of options
./a.out: ./a.out: option '-d' needs an argument.
usage: ./a.out [-b] [-s string] [-d int]
  -b : set somebool to true
  -s : what follows -s sets some string
  -d : some int parameter
  -help  Display this list of options
  --help  Display this list of options
.
usage: ./a.out [-b] [-s string] [-d int]
  -b : set somebool to true
  -s : what follows -s sets some string
  -d : some int parameter
  -help  Display this list of options
  --help  Display this list of options
```

I was not able to find out why the error/usage message is printed three times. This also happens to all the other code examples I found online. Is this a problem in the `Arg` module or is it somehow not used correctly in these examples?

Comment: What version of the compiler do you use? (I've managed to reproduce under 4.04.2 as of right now)

Comment: Running with OCaml 4.02.3 does not cause this behavior. I suggest you check [OCaml bug-tracker](https://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view_all_bug_page.php) to see whether this problem was reported before. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to reproduce the bug with OCaml 4.04.2, but not with 4.02.3, so it would seem that there is some sort of regression going on there.

So, one thing you could do is sticking to an older version of OCaml, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Instead, you could use an alternative standard library, such as Jane Street's `Core`. It has a module named `Command` which allows you to write command-line interfaces just like the one you're trying to run.

An extensive tutorial for this module is available [here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/command-line-parsing.html).

As an example, here is the CLI from Rosetta using `Command`:

```
open Core

let spec =
  let open Command.Spec in
  empty
    +> flag "-b" (no_arg) ~doc:"Sets some flag"
    +> flag "-s" (optional_with_default "" string) ~doc:"STRING Some string parameter"
    +> flag "-d" (optional_with_default 0 int) ~doc:"INTEGER Some int parameter"

let command =
  Command.basic
    ~summary:"My awesome CLI"
    spec
    (fun some_flag some_string some_int () ->
       printf " %b '%s' %d\n" some_flag some_string some_int
    )

let () =
  Command.run command
```

---

**EDIT** : This bug was known and [is going to be fixed in OCaml 4.05](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/999).

Comment: I am not very experienced with opam, but it seems like `opam install core` requires to downgrade the package zarith to 1.4.1. Unfortunately, my project depends on zarith 1.5. Other command-line packages like `getopt` or `getopts` seem to depend on an older version of zarith aswell.

Nevertheless thank you for your response. I guess that having multiple versions of the same package would make everything a lot more complicated, which means that I rather wait for OCaml 4.05. instead.

Comment: Just a thought: have you run `opam update` before trying to install `core`?

Comment: No, but `opam update` sadly did not change the required version of zarith.

Comment: This is curious. I have `zarith` 1.5 and `core` 0.9.1 installed on my system. Also, I see no dependency between these two packages.

Comment: This is strange indeed. I just installed core which downgraded `zarith`. Running `opam update` and `opam upgrade` afterwards upgraded `zarith` to 1.5 again without any issues.

Comment: The default OPAM constraint solver is not very powerful, and it is not rare to see it suggests unnecessary downgrades.  If you do not enable aspcud solver in it, you should try it.